# Como trabalhar com resource no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Minha dúvida se resume basicamente as ações/actions Store, Update e Destroy.

- Estou querendo criar um novo registro no banco de dados, devo para tanto utilizar o verbo POST para chamar a action store?
- Quero atualizar um registro já existente em banco, devo utilizar que verbo, a action será store ou update?

Pergunto isso pois na documentação do Laravel "Actions Handled By Resource Controller" https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers existem alguns verbos e action que levantam essa duvida quanto a sua utilização.

Obs: Se eu estiver certo, as action update e destroy devem ser utilizados para manipular arquivos no sistema de arquivos. Isso está certo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O resource no Laravel criar métodos para realização de CRUD.

Os métodos são usados para listar, atualizar, mostrar, criar e deletar registros.

Por exemplo, se você criar um resource para UsersController, você deverá ter os métodos `index (get)`, `create (get)`, `store (post)`, `edit (get)`, `update (put)`, `destroy (delete)`.

> Estou querendo criar um novo registro no banco de dados, devo para tanto utilizar o verbo POST para chamar a action store?

Sim, o método do resource equivalente a ação "criar" é o `store`. O método de requisição HTTP requirido é o POST.

O método `create` é apenas a interface para criação, por isso é um método GET.

> Quero atualizar um registro já existente em banco, devo utilizar que verbo, a action será store ou update?

Deverá ser `update`. O método `update` requer uma requisição do tipo `PUT`. É importante destacar isso, pois se estiver usando uma requisição do tipo `Ajax`, você precisará especificar esse método.

> Se eu estiver certo, as action update e destroy devem ser utilizados para manipular arquivos no sistema de arquivos. Isso está certo?

Não necessariamente um sistema de arquivos. O resource na verdade tem como objetivo tornar mais fácil a criação de um CRUD, baseando-se no REST, onde você tem cada url responsável por uma ação.

Geralmente, usa-se em  Laravel `update` para atualizar um registro, e `destroy`, para remover.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação esclarecedora Wallace.